# How to reload Gridview's Items after changing selected item in Spinner

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

In my application, I have a Spinner which includes list of categories and GridView to show list of

Images according to selected category.

My question is: "How to reload images on GridView after changing category in Spinner?"

Answer (score 2):

From the code that gets the selected category from the Spinner, get your GridView's adapter and then call clear() on it and then addAll(T... items) with the new category items you want to show.

Keep in mind that this assumes you've created the adapter by passing it a mutable List.

If you created the adapter with an immutable List or T[], then you can create a new adapter and set it on the GridView instead.

Comment: But notifyDataSetChanged has no parameter, how can I pass selected category GridView adapter in this case?

Comment: @Binngokute: I've edited my answer to address both your original and follow on questions.